# mingw32-make.exe exists yet no "make" command is present

Tags: gcc, mingw

I have the PATH set to `C:\MinGW\bin`, where the file `mingw32-make.exe` exists, which after some searching is the file required to use the "make" command. But, the command is not available. I have access to the `gcc` and `g++` compilers, so I'm sure the PATH set.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have `mingw32-make` present in the `%PATH%` variable, then the command `mingw32-make` should work. I suggest you to rename `mingw32-make.exe` into `make.exe`.

Comment: Yep! Exactly the problem. Thanks a bunch, I didn't know the executable's name was the command itself.

Comment: Actually, there is nothing magic. When you type the command `make` in the console, the console will search in all the `%PATH%` for several candidates based on the extension. Example: it will try to look for `make.bat`, `make.exe`, `make.com`, I am not sure about all the extensions. If the console has found an existing program, it will create a new process. If not it will write an the error message.